# passing command line args in ruby and runtime args through gets

Tags: ruby

I wrote a code in ruby which basically takes 3 commandline args followed by userinput from the keyboard. The problem is when i am executing the code without command line, it is able to read userinput but with command line it is throwing error `gets': No such file or directory - 3024 (Errno::ENOENT)
Dont understand why

```
class Matching
  attr_reader :sys_count
  def initialize()
    @sys_count = gets
    throw "Bad count" unless @sys_count.to_i > 0
  end
  def get_match
    count = @sys_count
    return nil unless count
    ret = count

    count.to_i.times do
      ret += gets
    end
    ((count.to_i * (count.to_i - 1))/2).times do
      while true do
        line = gets
        ret += line
        break if line == "\n"
      end
    end

    ret
  end

  def packet
    str = get_match
    return nil unless str
    "matched 0\njava\n" + str
  end
end
CONN=ARGV[0]
CONFIG=ARGV[1]
OUT_BASE=ARGV[2]
obj=Matching.new()
out=obj.packet
print out
```

Is there any workaround to make it work
~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically state that you need the input from the input device, as opposed to command line arguments `ARGV`, and since `gets` is generic, you've to be specific in this case to avoid confusions or misinterpretation.

So, replace all `gets` with `$stdin.gets` or `STDIN.gets`, which gets the input from the standard input.

Comment: @Sur123 glad to have helped :)